# How to get command output in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I'm wondering, how do I get the output of an execwait command in NSIS. For example, if I run `tree`, how would I get the output, which would be the actual tree?

Comment: NSIS has instructions to enumerate files, see FindFirst in the helpfile

Comment: The command I'm running isn't tree, it's a lot more complex. Tree is just an example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't do that with ExecWait, you have to use one of the plugins: [nsExec](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsExec/nsExec.txt), [ExecDos](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in)
or [ExecCmd](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecCmd_plug-in)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using: nsExec::ExecToStack 'command', pop $1 (for the exit code), pop $1 (for the ouput)

Comment: ExecCmd now states: "This plug-in is no longer updated and has been superseded by the [ExecDos plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in)."

Comment: @Anders im using execwait to launch an exe but it is stuck on this command and it never proceeds.  ExecWait "$INSTDIR\Application\abc.exe"

Comment: @Dragon How is this related? ExecWait waits until the process ends. Is it stuck waiting for stdin?

Comment: I want to run a command get its output and show it in textbox I'm using the following code and always getting 0 as the output

 nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell -NoProfile -Command "$(& {$Args[0]})" "where code"'
 Pop $Output ;
 
${NSD_SetText} $LocationTextbox "$Output"