# nsis execwait returning 7

Tags: nsis, execute

Following line in my nsis script is returning 7 :

```
ExecWait '"$mysqlfolder\bin\mysqldump" --user=$MySQLUser --password=$MysqlPassword --execute="tcm > D:\db_test.sql"' $2
```

I would like to know whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the exit code is not from mysqldump? You could verify this by running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

In this case the problem could be the stdout redirection (`>`), this type of redirection is implemented in cmd.exe so unless --execute calls cmd.exe it is not going to work.

If you want to capture the output (of the "root" child process) you have two options:

- Prefix your command line with `cmd.exe /C` (Use ReadEnvStr "COMSPEC" if you need to support Win9x)
- Use one of the [exec plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4019009/3501) that will capture the output.